# Azure DevOps Board Access

Tags: azure-devops, devops, readonly, azure-boards

I have a request form my customer that they want access to my organization's DevOps board to monitor the progress of work items in each sprint.

Is there an option to provide  READ-ONLY access to DevOps BOARD to external users? Restrict them,

1. To view only existing Sprint's work Items
2. To create a new work items
3. Disable option to view Repo, pipelines, Wiki, Dashboard etc.

Added users to the Org user group with Basic level access and set the following permission in the project settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that permissions in Azure DevOps are managed in multiple places for individual services. The good news is that you can use the same user groups everywhere.

To view only existing Sprint's work Items, the predefined **Reader** role should be what you need. Or the same set of permissions, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops).

You can disable the group any **repository permissions**, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops).

**Wiki** also has its own permission settings as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops).

For **pipelines** .... you guessed it, it's again in different place, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops).